# What is the difference between memory limit, timeout setting at lambda vs Greengrass lambda configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

What is the difference between memory limit, timeout setting at **lambda** vs **Greengrass lambda configuration**?

**At Lambda:**

[image]

**At Greengrass Lambda configuration:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The memory limit of the Lambda function defines the maximum memory it can use, this also has a direct impact on the amount of CPU your Lambda has access to. This will directly affect the performance of your Lambda, either the speed at which it executes or resource allocation errors (for example not enough memory to process the action).

> The amount of memory available to the function while it is running. Choose an amount [between 128 MB and 3,008 MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) in 64-MB increments.
>
> Lambda allocates CPU power linearly in proportion to the amount of memory configured. At 1,792 MB, a function has the equivalent of one full vCPU (one vCPU-second of credits per second).

The timeout of the Lambda function defines the maximum duration the Lambda can run for, after this point the Lambda function will no longer continue.

> The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run before stopping it. The default is 3 seconds. The maximum allowed value is 900 seconds.

When deploying new Lambdas both of these should be set to match their expected threshold so ensure you do look at the metrics to identify these thresholds (with a little bit of wiggle room if needed).